# How to specify HDFS Location for Hive's partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hdfs directory,in that I have so many files.This directory is getting continuous data.Now what I am trying is to create a external partitioned table for that HDFS location like as,

```
create external table sensor_data(sensor_name string,alert_type string,isvalid_alert boolean,value string,alert_generated_time bigint)
 partitioned by (mac_id string)
clustered by(sensor_name) into 13 buckets
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
lines terminated by '\n'
location '/user/test';
```

table is creating successfully,but while selecting it doesn't show anything.
select * from sensor_data where mac_id='mac_id2';
select * from sensor_data;

I tried these two ways,what I am missing is not able to understand.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A partitioned table in hive has a specific structure:

At the table location `/user/test` you must have a folder for each partition:

```
/user/test/mac_id=1
/user/test/mac_id=2
...
```

Also, when you create new folders/partitions - you need to update the table metadata by running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE sensor_data`

Note that the data must have the delimiters you define.

Also since your table is clustered you need the data to be clustered.

I would suggest first inserting data into this table using hive's `INSERT INTO TABLE` to see the correct format of the data.